# How to get EF6 code-first one-to-one relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I wrote modelbuilder in model context class for EF 6 code-first one to one relationship, but it didn't work.

```
[Table("ProductPrice", Schema = "Product")]
public class ProductPrice
{
    [Key]
    public int ProductPriceID { get; set; }
    public float MonthlyPrice { get; set; }
    public float YearlyPrice { get; set; }

    public virtual PriceUnit PriceUnit { get; set; }
}

[Table("PriceUnit", Schema = "General")]
public class PriceUnit
{
    [Key]
    public int PriceUnitID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ShortName { get; set; }
    public string Contract { get; set; }

    public virtual ProductPrice ProductPrice { get; set; }
}
```

`DbContext`:

```
public DbSet<PriceUnit> PriceUnits { get; set; }
public DbSet<ProductPrice> ProductPrices { get; set; }

modelBuilder.Entity<PriceUnit>()
       .HasOptional(p => p.ProductPrice)
       .WithRequired(c => c.PriceUnit)
       .Map(c => c.MapKey("PriceUnitID"))
       .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

I'm trying to create a one-on-one relationship but it's not working the way I want

Comment: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90OTE.png) When we write these articles, it was tried that a foreign key was not added correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `ModelBuilder` settings with

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ProductPrice>()
    .HasRequired(p => p.PriceUnit)
    .WithOptional(u => u.ProductPrice)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

And edit the model like :

```
[Table("ProductPrice", Schema = "Product")]
public class ProductPrice
{
    [Key]
    public int ProductPriceID { get; set; }
    public float MonthlyPrice { get; set; }
    public float YearlyPrice { get; set; }        
    public int PriceUnitID { get; set; }
    public virtual PriceUnit PriceUnit { get; set; }
}
```

Note that `PriceUnitID` will create a foreign key.

Comment: PriceUnit in ModelBuilder gives some error?

Comment: @Elifşahin I don't think it can cause an error.

Comment: 'ProductPrice' does not contain a definition of 'PriceUnit' and there is no accessible extension method 'PriceUnit' that accepts a first argument of type 'ProductPrice' (could you have a usage restrictions or limitations reference missing?)

Comment: @Elifşahin Just updated the code. try it now